# DAX syntax to calculate sum base on condition on another table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two table TMain and TZone, relationship between them is ST1 vs GeoKey, and ST2 vs Geokey

[image]

I would like to write a DAX syntax to get the result as in SQL query below

```
SELECT    
SUM(    case when rou_1st.GeoCode = 'N'
         then ISNull(tm.Data1, 0) 
         else 0     end     +   case when rou_2nd.GeoCode = 'N'
         then ISNull(tm.Data2, 0) 
         else 0     end ) As N,

SUM(    case when rou_1st.GeoCode = 'I'
         then ISNull(tm.Data1, 0) 
         else 0     end     +   case when rou_2nd.GeoCode = 'I'
         then ISNull(tm.Data2, 0) 
         else 0     end ) As I    
FROM TMain tm left join TZone rou_1st  ON tm.ST1 = rou_1st.GeoKey left join TZone rou_2nd ON tm.ST2 = rou_2nd.GeoKey
```

I am very new to DAX syntax, and just start to learn the curve that is why I would need some helps from the group on that.

Regards,

Veasna

Comment: Before using DAX, your data model (tables and their relations) must be re-designed. In their current form, they violate key principles behind dimensional modeling, and will make DAX either too complicated or impossible. We can help you fix the data model, but you need to explain the meaning of these tables and their fields and relations.

Comment: TMain is the movement of the flight where one flight can have one or multiple route. TZone is the category of the route either domestic 'N' or international 'I'. As example for the first row, ST1: BKK,  Data1[Pax] : 20 and ST2: ST2, Data2[Pax]: 11 What could be a better way to re-model as nature of the movement should represent same way as what currently table presented?

Answer (score 0):

Well since your query has left join, in power bi you can create relations that will work  as join for you in power bi 
Add both the tables in power bi 
table 1  - Tmain 
table 2 - TZone
create a new table (for that go to modeling click on new table and write the dax) Tzone 2nd = TZone :- this will create a replica of TZone

Now in relationship section create relationship between Tmain and Tzone at column - ST1 and Geokey and another relation between tmain and tzone 2nd at column ST2 and Geokey

now create two columns in Tmain using dax

Geocode = RELATED(Tzone[GoeCode]) 
Geocode secound = RELATED(Tzone1[GoeCode])

this will bring the related values of GoeCode to  Tmain then create  new columns with following dax query

For fist sum -

N=if(Tmain[Geocode]="N",if(ISBLANK(Tmain[Data1]),0,Tmain[Data1]))+ if(Tmain[Geocode secound]="N",if(ISBLANK(Tmain[Data2]),0,Tmain[Data2]))

For secound sum - 
I=if(Tmain[Geocode]="I",if(ISBLANK(Tmain[Data1]),0,Tmain[Data1]))+ if(Tmain[Geocode secound]="I",if(ISBLANK(Tmain[Data2]),0,Tmain[Data2]))

Add values generated by these columns in a new measure